# how to change the default location of the flexslider's thumbnail

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider

Good day all

after inserting the Flexslider into my project i am now stuck with this task.
the task is to change the position of the thumbnail by default its at the bottom but I want it to be on the right hand side of the slider. further I also want the thumbnails images to be on the same row with an arrow at both ends as a navigator. anybody help please.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the thumbnail images to be located anywhere, you can use absolute positioning.

For the thumbnails to have an arrow navigation, follow the instructions on flexslider's site as [demonstrated here.](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html)